# Convert FullCalendar Event timeFormat to 12 hr for Month view - bug?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar 2.3.1. I'm trying to convert the time (for example 13:00-14:00) in the month view into 12hr format. Here is my current timeFormat option value:

```
timeFormat: 'h(:mm)t'
```

and some example event json:

```
{
id: "40163152543",
original_id: "3231",
title: "Conference Call",
description: "",
start: "2015-11-20T13:00:00",
end: "2015-11-20T14:00:00",
allDay: false,
color: ""
}
```

In Week and Day views I am seeing 1p-2p, which is what I want, but in month view I am still seeing 13:00-14:00. Same issue in v 2.6.0! Is this a bug??

[image: Month View Does not Display right timeFormat]

[image: Day View Displays Correctly]

Answer (score 1):

It should work. I tried it locally and works fine as per your configuration.
But still you face same issue then try by giving [view specific option](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/). May this will solve.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It did not fix my issue. I am also using an extensive Full Calendar extension so I will report the bug to them and report back.

Answer (score 1):

So in the extension library I'm using there was an eventRender callback that I was missing that was overriding the timeFormat option. This is the working override if curious:

```
eventRender: 
    function(event, element, view) 
    {   
        if(event.end !== null && view.name == 'month')
        {
            timeformat = event.start.format('h(:mm)t') + ' - ' + event.end.format('h(:mm)t');
            element.find('.fc-time').html(timeformat);  
        }
    }
```

If you have this issue, lookout for an eventRender callback! More documentation on it here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/

Very useful callback, also cool way to do view-specific options, especially with the default view, and @ChintanMirani answer was great too!